Pandas dataframe - keep values that are certain number of rows apart
I have a column of 0s and 1s. I only want to keep 1s in the output column only if they end up being at least 4 rows apart.
Note that simply doing diff() is not a solution, because this would eliminate too many 1s. Here's an example:
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ix':list(range(12)), 'in':[1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]})
df['out'] = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0] # desred output

    ix  in  out
0    0   1    1
1    1   0    0
2    2   0    0
3    3   1    0  # this 1 needs to become 0
4    4   1    1  # we keep this 1, because the previously kept one is sufficiently far
5    5   0    0
6    6   1    0
7    7   0    0
8    8   1    1
9    9   0    0
10  10   0    0
11  11   1    0

Intuitively it seems like it should be solved with some combination of grouping, diff and cumsum(), but I haven't been able to figure it out.

What should be the output if the row in index 4 was 0?

IIUC, you cannot vectorize your operation since the fate of one row depends on that of the previous rows.
Thus, you must loop. One option is to use numba to improve the speed:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def keep_apart(a, N=3):
    out = []
    wait = 0
    for x in a:
        if x == 1:
            if wait > 0:
                out.append(0)
                wait -= 1
            else:
                out.append(1)
                wait = N
        else:
            out.append(0)
            wait -= 1
    return out

df['out'] = keep_apart(df['in'].to_numpy())

Output:
    ix  in  out
0    0   1    1
1    1   0    0
2    2   0    0
3    3   1    0
4    4   1    1
5    5   0    0
6    6   1    0
7    7   0    0
8    8   1    1
9    9   0    0
10  10   0    0
11  11   1    0

Alternative example:
    ix  in  out
0    0   1    1
1    1   0    0
2    2   0    0
3    3   1    0
4    4   0    0
5    5   0    0
6    6   1    1
7    7   1    0
8    8   1    0
9    9   0    0
10  10   0    0
11  11   1    1


Because you modify as you go along the column row by row, groupby or cumsum or such can't give you proper answer. You could use simple for loop.
in_col = "in"
out_col = "out"
distance = 4
df[out_col] = df[in_col]
idxs = df[in_col].eq(1).index.tolist()
if idxs:
  prev = idxs[0]
  for idx in idxs[1:]:
    if idx - prev + 1 <= distance:
      df.loc[idx, out_col] = 0
    else:
      df.loc[idx, out_col] = 1
      prev = idx  
  print(df)



    ix  in  out
0    0   1    1
1    1   0    0
2    2   0    0
3    3   1    0
4    4   1    1
5    5   0    0
6    6   1    0
7    7   0    0
8    8   1    1
9    9   0    0
10  10   0    0
11  11   1    0


import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': list(range(12)), 'val': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]})

val = df['val'].values

@njit
def filter_ones(val):
    res = np.zeros_like(val)
    
    indices_for_1 = np.where(val == 1)[0]#[ 0  3  4  6  8 11]
    
    last_kept_idx = -np.inf

    for idx in indices_for_1:
        if idx - last_kept_idx >= 4:
            res[idx] = 1
            last_kept_idx = idx

    return res

res = filter_ones(val)
df['res'] = res
print(df)
'''
    id  val  res
0    0    1    1
1    1    0    0
2    2    0    0
3    3    1    0
4    4    1    1
5    5    0    0
6    6    1    0
7    7    0    0
8    8    1    1
9    9    0    0
10  10    0    0
11  11    1    0
'''

